# Docker 'docker-compose up' not recognizing sqlite3 commands with valid path

Tags: docker, sqlite, docker-compose, node-sqlite3

I have a nodejs application paired with a Sqlite3 db I am trying to dockerize. Specifically, I want to be able to run in terminal 'docker-compose up' and have the nodejs give output from my nodejs app.

Within the dir of the application there exists the node modules/dependencies along with the app.js file, and a 'db' folder containing a database.db file.

Within database.db a table already exists, as I did not want to hard-code this within node and wanted to do it through sql first.

So the issue I face is, within docker-compose.yml I have 2 services: 1) the sqlite3 service (which needs to be first as I need to run the commands to create the table before app runs) and 2) the service for the app itself.

The error I am getting when trying to run 'docker-compose up' is as follows:

```
 Error: near "db": syntax error
sqlite3db exited with code 1
```

I have tried to change the file path several times, but it looks like no matter what I do it does not like either the syntax on my command, or the path itself.

Can't find any reference or examples online of someone doing this in yml, so If anyone has seen or done this before and can show me where I am wrong on the **command** or the **service** it would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
 sqlite3:
   image: nouchka/sqlite3
   container_name: "sqlite3db"
   stdin_open: true
   tty: true
   volumes:
     - ./db/database.db:/root/db/database.db
   command: ".open root/db/database.db"

 transactions:
     build: .
     container_name: "myprocessor"
     image: debian/latest
     links:
         - sqlite3
     depends_on:
         "sqlite3":
             condition: service_healthy
     environment:
         SQLITE3_CONTAINER: sqlite3db
```

Comment: SQLite is an embedded database, and it doesn't have a separate server.  You wouldn't run a dedicated container for it (unlike PostgreSQL or MariaDB); instead, you need to mount storage of some sort containing the SQLite database file into the container.  (If you did use a separate relational database then your container could be stateless, which is often a plus.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is using dot in your volume path:

https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/675

Comment: I tried this before and got a similar error: 

`The path /db/database.db is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.`

Perhaps this error is just the next one to tackle, but it still looks like path issue

Comment: The dot on the beginning defines the current directory if you run the command from shell. Try to put the absolute path to your File Sharing.

Comment: Also try to mount only directory, not files: -v ./db:/root/db